# how to use readline without and EOF character java

Tags: java, sockets, readline, eof

i am trying to implement a simple server application in java.

all it does is read in a message on the tcp/ip and stores it as a string this is my code.

```
    try{
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("cannot open input buffer");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    clientSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);

    //read first bit of message
    message = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(message);
    //as message is an undefined length we need to loop and check for the springer miller 
    //end mark /Request
    while(message.contains("/Request") == false  )
    {
        try {
        message = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(message);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("cannot open input buffer");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }       

    //reply
    out.println(outputLine);
```

the problem i am having is that the message does not appear to have an EOF. it is another companies protocol i am translating into mine, thats the purpose of the program so i cannot add a EOF to the message

the information a get if i run the program is:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: http://htng.org/1.1/Listener.Wsdl#ReceiveMessageAsync
User-Agent: Java/1.6.0_24
Host: 192.168.0.32:8080
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 3009
```

then it hangs when it should read the message body.

i have never used java in my life before and do not want to write a binary socket readed to detect my own EOF.

is there a way to read for x seconds and then return

thank you for any help.

P.S have already successfully built the program in C++ but need to port in to java because destined machine is unknown.

Comment: You'll need to define what you mean by "a message". It looks like you're using HTTP, so the message length is defined by the content length header. However, there are plenty of HTTP servers already written in Java - why would you want to write another?

Comment: its a stand alone application to translate an tcp/ip protocol into an rs232 protocol so two servers can talk. by message i mean just text. there server adds the http bit i have put up and the body is xml.

Comment: @Skeith: But the HTTP part is telling you how much data you have to read. So why not use code which already knows how to read data from an HTTP request?

Comment: because my company has a server but it is designed to listen for the incoming communication on an rs232 port. my boss wants a light weight interface application in java, so i am attempting to treat the message as plain text. this worked in c++ but the java read blocks.

Comment: @Skeith: I suspect it doesn't *really* work in C++, because if the other end of the connection is holding it open, how can you tell the difference between the end of the message and network lag? Or are you just reading the XML document and assuming there's no more data after the document-closing tag? Again, if the client is posting HTTP requests, I'd suggest using an existing HTTP server.

Comment: i am using test scripts to simulate the there companies server at the moment. i check the bytes read against the number in the http header and send an ack char. i am reasonably good at c++ as i have been doing it for year but my employer has decided that my work from now on must be done in java and wants me to learn it but im in way over my head. i know im being difficult by not just using a http server but its not my decision on how were doing this :(

Comment: Ah, so in the C++ you *are* using the HTTP header... so you'd want to do the same in Java, right? But you're currently ignoring the HTTP headers. Has your boss *really* said that you have to reinvent the wheel? Have you presented them with the idea that you could use someone else's HTTP code, and just write the code to *use* the data yourself?

Comment: what do you mean "someone else's HTTP code" ?

Comment: @Skeith: I mean taking an open source HTTP library - either standalone, or as part of something like Tomcat. There are *loads* of HTTP implementations available... I see no reason to introduce yet another.

Comment: i figured simply opening a port and reading basic text from it would be much simpler then implementing tomcat or apachie as they are rather complex ?

Comment: @Skeith: Well, even in your sample code you're ignoring things like the character set specified by the client. Doing this sort of thing *properly* takes some effort. But fundamentally, if you want to run an HTTP server, there are plenty of existing options - writing your own seems like a poor choice to me. Getting Tomcat up and running isn't that hard, and there are probably lighter-weight options available too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BufferedReader.readline](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) will return null on EOF and not throw an exception.

Moreover, the "other companies protocol" seems to be SOAP over HTTP. 
Maybe you want to use a HTTP or SOAP library? Others here will be able to give pointers...

Otherwise you can use the following approach:
readLine once to get check if the method is indeed POST (otherwise the Content-Length header might not be there) and the path is correct.
readLine until it either returns an empty line (or null), to read all the HTTP headers. 
While doing that look out for a line starting with Content-Length, to determine the length of the following XML data.
create a char[] of the correct length and use `in.read(cbuf, 0, cbuf.length)` to read the xml into the created buffer cbuf.

Comment: SOAP is in regards to reading the XML, that bit i have already taken care of it is receiving the message that is troubling me. the exception handler was an idea where the read would return with what ever it had after 5 seconds if no EOF was found.

Comment: Have you condidered the possibility that all the XML comes in one line (without a newline at the end)?

Comment: sorry to be thick but is cbut the char[] or a java class?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing protocols on top of TCP/IP is tricky, and requires quite a lot of understanding of how networking, sockets and your OS:s I/O work.

Further, implementing HTTP is surprisingly complex - on top of the network complexity.

I'm politely suggesting that you probably are in deep water, as you have to ask questions at this level, and probably need more help than you can get on SO.

...anyway.

If the server you are reading from is trying to talk http, use an existing component for it.  Apache HttpComponents if probably a good choice. I don't really buy that it forges http headers, and I suggest that you skip your "lightweight" approach.

Here is some network-i/o basic facts.

Network writes are packet oriented. Tcp/ip generally tries to stuff as much as possible into every packet (using some smart algorithms).  That means that if you write 4000 bytes, the message is split up into several packets that are arbitrarily sized, but normally less than 1500 byte - depending on the network equipment.  It also means that
if you write less than a packet, your writes may be merged into one packet. (Packets may also be split and merged along they way.)

In order to send messages over the stream ( which itself is transported in packets...) you need to know in advance how long the messages are, or, read a full packet (do a .read() into a large buffer), parse the contents, and extract and contruct complete messages in some smart way. Exactly what http does. (among things)

TCP/IP is certainly NOT line-oriented, so your newlines are totally ignored. HTTP uses the content-length (and some other tricks, as it may not always be defined) to send "messages" over a single tcp/ip stream, that may or may not be closed when a message is completely sent.

Comment: in c++ i am using recv(new_fd, message, sizeof message, 0). new_fd being the socket and message a char array. one read of this get the header and a second gets the whole xml message. according to what iv read the java equivelent is a bufferreader and lineread but this reads the header as 8 peices and the xml as one but if i do 9 reads it never returns. if i send message 2 it works(2000 bites) but message 1 (3000 bites) hangs. i do kind of understand tcp/ip but i may be using the wrong approach in java. thank you for you help